# Parse JSON String to JSON Object in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, parsing

I have a JSON String returned by my SOAP web service in .NET. It is as follows:

```
{
 "checkrecord":
   [
     {
      "rollno":"abc2",
      "percentage":40,
      "attended":12,
      "missed":34
     }
  ],
 "Table1":[]
}
```

Now I want to parse this string to a JSON Object. I also read [this](http://programmingsolution.net/post/JSON-to-Object-Conversion-in-C.aspx) where they have used  this line of code:

```
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);
```

So can I do the same by replacing "json" with my string name. Also do I need to reference any other dll except the NewtonSoft.dll ?

BTW, Here is the full webservice [code](http://pastie.org/2931501)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

use `new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object>(jsonString)`

You need System.Web.Extensions dll and import the following namespace.

Namespace: System.Web.Script.Serialization

for more info **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)**

Comment: hey thanks !! is this right ??  JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<object>(json);  Also , when I write this line of code in vs 2008, I m getting error saying " The type or namespace JavaScriptSerializer could not be found" I have added Newtonsoft.dll as reference, do I need to add something else

Comment: also how do I return the Object? Do I need to change data type of my webmethod to JSON Object?

Comment: updated my answer.. you dnt need newtonsoft.dll! zzz.. what do you mean return the object??

Comment: I want to know when I convert the JSON String I have into a JSON Object using the method u have mentioned, what will be the format of the JSON object and how will it look like? Also, I need to return that JSON object so that it can be used on my client Android app

Comment: well you cannot send a c# object to the client you need to serialize it again and end it and deserialize it in the client side code.

Comment: http://atsung.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/javascriptserializer-example/ shows how to work with this class.. Please google you will find everything

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5392/discussion-between-parth-90-and-baz1nga)

Comment: @capdragon: Not unless he's your father.

Comment: @Baz1nga: I added the System.Web.Extensions reference and then "using System.Web.Script.Serialization;" but this line:

var bla = new JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<object>(jsonString);

...failed with the dreaded red "who goes there?" on Deserialize. IOW, this:

var bla = new JavaScriptSerializer.

prompts nothing at all from Intellisense; though it seems to know who JavaScriptSerializer is, it doesn't recognize it as having any available methods.

Comment: you need to instantiate an object of  type JavaScriptSerializer as follows  new JavaScriptSerializer().. else I need to see more of your code to help

Comment: How can one pass in the <object>?

Comment: @Demodave, instantiate the serializer on one line, then call the generic function on the next line. I had the same problem using the syntax in the answer.

Answer (score 15):

I see that this question is very old, but this is the solution I used for the same problem, and it seems to require a bit less code than the others.

As @Maloric mentioned in his answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459155/how-to-access-json-object-in-c-sharp) question:

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(myJsonString);
```

To use JObject, you need the following in your class file

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

Comment: For some reason .NET's `System.Object` and `System.Json` are unavailable in UWP projects, so this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

Another choice besides JObject is [System.Json.JsonValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672709%28v=vs.95%29) for Weak-Typed JSON object.

It also has a `JsonValue blob = JsonValue.Parse(json);` you can use.  The blob will most likely be of type `JsonObject` which is derived from `JsonValue`, but could be `JsonArray`.  Check the `blob.JsonType` if you need to know.

And to answer you question, YES, you may replace `json` with the name of your actual variable that holds the JSON string. ;-D

There is a **System.Json.dll** you should add to your project References.

-Jesse

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone trying to locate this .dll on their system, it looks like this is Silverlight dll available with .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned that you are using Newtonsoft.dll you can convert a JSON string to an object by using its facilities:

```
MyClass myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(your_json_string);

[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public string myVar {get; set;}
    etc.
}
```