# how to access JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

I receive the following Json through a web service:

```
  {
     report: {
      Id: "aaakkj98898983"
     }
  }
```

I want to get value of the Id. How to do this in C#?
THANKS

Comment: What have you looked into? I mean, you know, there are several articles on using JSON in .Net...

Comment: You need to show some research effort before asking a question. What have you already tried?

Comment: Next time try to find an answer on your own before you ask a question

Answer (score 92, accepted):

First, download [Newtonsoft's Json Library](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx), then parse the json using JObject.  This allows you to access the properties within pretty easily, like so:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace testClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var myJsonString = "{report: {Id: \"aaakkj98898983\"}}";
            var jo = JObject.Parse(myJsonString);
            var id = jo["report"]["Id"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(id);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```