# Dynamic Json string access a value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
    {
  "ErrorNumber": 10,
  "Type": "ValidationException",
  "Message": "A validation exception occurred",
  "Elements": [
    {
      "ContactID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "Name": "Test AB",
      "EmailAddress": "abc@gmail.com",
      "Addresses": [
        {
          "AddressType": "POBOX",
          "ValidationErrors": []
        }
      ],
      "Phones": [],
      "ContactGroups": [],
      "IsCustomer": true,
      "ContactPersons": [],
      "HasValidationErrors": true,
      "ValidationErrors": [
        {
          "Message": "The contact name Test AB is already assigned to another contact. The contact name must be unique across all active contacts."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Tried to deserialize the object.

```
var x = ((Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Client.ApiException)ex.InnerException).ErrorContent;
                dynamic parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x);
```

I have a dynamic Json string which is coming from Xero API exception. How can I access the value "ValidationErrors" and the Message?

Comment: Can you provide the programming language you are using and what did you try so far?

Comment: C# code.    dynamic parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x); but I cannot seems to get access to array inside array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to access JSON object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459155/how-to-access-json-object-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I have tried it but its not working

Comment: Could you add your code snippet to the question?

Comment: `var result = JObject.Parse(error)["Elements"][0]["ValidationErrors"][0]` However your question is not very clear...You could deserialize this properly, though who knows what funky format they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `json.net` you can just navigate the graph with string indexers

```
var errors = JObject.Parse(json)["Elements"][0]["ValidationErrors"];

foreach (var error in errors)
   Console.WriteLine(error["Message"]);
```

**Output**

```
The contact name Test AB is already assigned to another contact. The contact name must be unique across all active contacts.
```

Comment: Throwing an exception "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty."

Comment: @Shereen i pasted your ***exact*** json and it works for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/mvpPB7