# Add \r\n in string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, visual-studio

I am trying to construct JSON manually in C#.

For this I am using this string:

```
string Response = "{\r\n\"Token\":\"guid\"\r\n}";
```

But instead of this

```
{
 "Token" :"guid"
}
```

I have this

```
"{\r\n\"Token\":\"guid\"\r\n}"
```

I tried Environment.NewLine also with the same results.

What is wrong?

**Update**

1) As the response to the request I can send different answers: "Token" or "Request". I don't want no make this:

```
if(true) Result = Json(new { Token= "guid"});
else     Result = Json(new { Request = "data array"});
```

2) it is web api function. I need to have the "good" result on the browser site

```
public IHttpActionResult Logon([FromBody]Logon_Request model)
{
 //some logic
 string Response_Type=...;
 string Response_Value=...;

 string Response = "{\r\n\"" + Response_Type + "\":\"" + Response_Value + "\"\r\n}";
 IHttpActionResult Result = Ok(Response);

 return Result;
}
```

Comment: Note the debugger displays strings with escape chars.

Comment: I see this also at browser side. Using Postman.

Comment: What if you try `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(Response);`, does it output what you want?

Comment: Write your json to file, you'll see that it is as you expected.

Comment: I suspect Postman is doing the same thing then...  I *very* much doubt that you've actually got encoded text. (Why are you constructing JSON manually, anyway?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291680/parse-json-string-to-json-object-in-c-net

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking at the value of `Response` in the debugger.  If you make use of your value somewhere, you will see that it is actually correct.  As Alex K pointed out in the comments beneath your question, the debugger always displays strings with the escape characters, even when you use `Environment.NewLine`.

You can verify that it's actually, in fact, working correctly by outputting to the console (or to the immediate window, depending on your VS settings) by doing this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(Response);
```

One other side note: you should adhere to proper naming conventions for variables whenever possible -- e.g. `response` not `Response` -- for local variables.

Comment: I don't know what else to say.  I tested it, and it works fine for me.