# Convert string to json using C#

Tags: c#

i am beginner to C#, i have a very long string and want to convert it to json, string is

```
{"employees":
[{"id":0,"level":0,"label":"Product Names","subitems":
    [{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"Soren","subitemslevel3":
        [{"id":0,"level":2,"label":"AAAA"},{"id":0,"level":2,"label":"bbb"}]},
{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"Test","subitemslevel3":
        [{"id":0,"level":2,"label":"111"},{"id":0,"level":2,"label":"2222"}]}]},
\
```

any ideas?

Comment: Wrong Tag if you want it to do in c#. You already tried something?

Comment: I havent tried anything..dont have any idea

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291680/parse-json-string-to-json-object-in-c-net you may get some idea

Comment: It is already json. What do you want exactly ?

Comment: take a look at [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(yourVariable);
```

this is using Newtonsoft's json library that you can get from nuget.

Also JObject is the C# equivalent to a JSON object so that's probably something you'll want to use.

Answer (score 2):

u an also use,

```
JObject.Parse(urJsonString);
```

`JObject` is in `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

*You need to Deserialize your string as follows :*

```
// Your string here 
string str = @"[{"categories":
[{"id":0,"level":0,"label":"Product Names","subitems":
    [{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"Soren","subitemslevel3":
        [{"id":0,"level":2,"label":"AAAA"},{"id":0,"level":2,"label":"bbb"}]},
{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"Test","subitemslevel3":
        [{"id":0,"level":2,"label":"111"},{"id":0,"level":2,"label":"2222"}]}]},
{"id":0,"level":0,"label":"Product texts","subitems":
    [{"id":0,"level":1,"label":""},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"<p>Disney <strong>Princess<\/strong><\/p>\n"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"<p>Machines & Mechanisms - <strong>Middle<\/strong><\/p>\n"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"64738574"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"8765432"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"a"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"aa"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"ab"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"abe"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"aD!?"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"Bionicle"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"Disney Princess"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"er"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"foo foo"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"hej"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"igen"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"meta"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"metadata"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"metadata from kafka"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"Metatest"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"q"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"Simpsons"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"test"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"Test 123"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"Test Metadata 123"}]},{"id":0,"level":0,"label"      :"Specialist Terms","subitems":[{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"meta"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"new category 1111"},{"id":0,"level":1,"label":"secret category"}]}]}]";

// DeSerialize your object 
JavaScriptSerializer serializer1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object obje = serializer1.Deserialize(str, obj1.GetType());
```

Comment: i wrote string like you tell but after that it is showing error like ] expected, ; expected etc.

Comment: it is still giving error like ; missing , unrecognized escape sequence etc.

Comment: nd btw, what is obj1?

Comment: Here You need to define obj1 ,Its should be a class